# SP2-0552: Bind variable not declared - Oracle Version Dependant

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

There are lots of solution for the same error in PLSQL. I am not facing this in PLSQL, but in SQL. This happens in one version of oracle and not in another.

I have created a table `create table test(id number(10), empid number(10))`

Now when I am inserting data

```
SQL> insert into test(id,empid) values (1, &empid)
  2  /
SP2-0552: Bind variable "EMPID" not declared.
SQL>
```

The details of the database installation are

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
CORE    12.2.0.1.0      Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

Now the same query is working fine and data is getting inserted in

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.4.0      Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

**EDIT :** 
I did not do any "define" anywhere. It happens in new sessions also. This 12c version was previously updated from 11g. Define shows

```
SQL> define
DEFINE _DATE           = "06-AUG-18" (CHAR)
DEFINE _CONNECT_IDENTIFIER = "mydbname" (CHAR)
DEFINE _USER           = "myusername" (CHAR)
DEFINE _PRIVILEGE      = "" (CHAR)
DEFINE _SQLPLUS_RELEASE = "1101000600" (CHAR)
DEFINE _EDITOR         = "Notepad" (CHAR)
DEFINE _O_VERSION      = "Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production" (CHAR)
DEFINE _O_RELEASE      = "1202000100" (CHAR)
DEFINE 1               = "to" (CHAR)
DEFINE 2               = "be" (CHAR)
DEFINE 3               = "pathToMyInstallation\product\11.1.0\client_1\sqlplus\admin\glogin.sql" (CHAR)
SQL>
```

Comment: You're using a substitution variable, not a bind variable. Have to done something like `define empid = :empid` in your session? Does it still happen in a new 12c session, or if you `undefine empid`? What does `define` with no arguments show? (Please add to your question as formatted text, not as a comment or an image.)

Comment: I don't have access to 12.2, but code you wrote works OK on 12.1.0.2.0 64-bit (just tried it).